# Firewall: enable access on selected ports on external IP but allow any port on local IP Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

How do I allow all traffic that occurs on VLAN / internal ports without any blocking but on external IP I allow selected ports. so I want the machines on VLAN to communicate freely but I want restricted access from public IPs

assume **for instance (fictional IPs)**

Machine A

- 192.168.0.10 is local IP/ VLAN
- 234.45.23.44 is public IP

Machine B

- 192.168.0.11 is local IP/ VLAN
- 234.45.23.43 is public IP

Machine C

- 192.168.0.12 is local IP/ VLAN
- 234.45.23.67 is public IP

I do not want firewall for any traffic on 192.168.0.* but I want selected ports to be opened on each public IP depending on the machine

Comment: What OS/release are you asking about?  Ubuntu's main products use the *year.month* format so 21st month makes no sense  (20.21?)

Comment: VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)" but I don't think UFW syntax or commands changes from version to version